# MediaElement.js Audio player - interesting wrapping on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, mediaelement.js

[image]

As you can see from the above image, I have an issue with my audio player ONLY on mobile devices.  When the player loads, it looks like this, but when I click PLAY:

[image]

SHAZAM! It looks as it should.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<audio id="audioPlayer001" style="max-width:100%; width: 100%;">
     <source src="theFile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

**JS**

```
$('#audioPlayer001').mediaelementplayer();
```

I originally had the preload parameter in the audio tags, thinking that playing with that may correct things, since the player is only wonky before you click PLAY, but no such luck `auto, metadata and none` have no effect.

Comment: Which browser did you use on your mobile device?

Comment: its looks to me that its because the white bar before you play is to big to fit inside the black square. Once you press play the bar is realizing its not that big and can now fit inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

Tried with your code. Used the default [mediaelementplayer.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/3.2.3/mediaelementplayer.min.css) styling provided with the library. It works as expected, even on a mobile.

So, the only explanation as to why this occurs for you is probably because you are over-riding the default styling.

Ensure that your stylesheets using !important properties do not override the default styles of the player. Use the **device toolbar** (`ctrl+shift+M` for Chrome) in the web developer tools to check exactly what styles are being applied.

p.s. Did you try to load mediaelementplayer.min.css at the end i.e. after all other stylesheets? Perhaps if you provide more information about your stylesheet/html markup, I could update my answer.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
 $('#audioPlayer001').mediaelementplayer();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/3.2.4/mediaelementplayer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/3.2.4/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>

<audio id="audioPlayer001" style="max-width:100%; width: 100%;">
    <source src="http://hcmaslov.d-real.sci-nnov.ru/public/mp3/Beatles/04%20Beatles%20for%20Sale/The%20Beatles%20-%20Beatles%20for%20Sale%20-%2001%20No%20Reply.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

You could also test this on your cellphone via the link http://www.niketpathak.com/app_external/test.html

Comment: the <link href="/css/mediaelementplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> is at the very bottom of the stack order. After that link, it's nothing but Javascript libraries.

Comment: I even put the link after ALL of the javascript references, still a wonky layout until you click play.

Comment: okay, I updated my answer. Check for the styles while using the device toolbar.

Comment: I use the Device Toolbar all the time to emulate mobile devices that we do not have in house. Plus I use it to check responsiveness AND touch-events.  Still no dice about the styles though. I've been monitoring the styles tab in my developer tools from day one.

Comment: Since the suggested method is not working, and no one has offered any alternative solutions, I cannot award the bounty.

Comment: @Murphy1976 if you are not over-riding the styles, it should work as expected, I have confirmed this to be working for me, it is responsive, maybe the problem is _something else_? without replicating your complete code(html + stylesheets + JS), nobody can help you diagnose it.

Comment: the code that I have submitted is the only code I am using.

Comment: I will update my answer with a code snippet if it helps.

Comment: the bounty is over, I went with a different solution.

Comment: yep, no worries, updated the post, just to show you that it does work. :) Cheers.